# Getting <a ref> image icon

Tags: html, css

Studying webpages to learn html/css/javascript

Got confused when I thought that most images were linked to or loaded locally... It seems like on spotify their search button is using something I don't understand to load the magnifying glass.

```
.spoticon-search-32:before {
    content: "\f141";
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

If I edit content the picture of the search button goes away so I know its the content that is responsible for the picture. But where the hell is it loading it from? it's not a .png or .jpg extension either...

Comment: Take a look at icon fonts, here explained a bit in depth: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/how-to-use-and-embed-an-icon-font-on-your-website. Your question is answered at:  3. Using Icons as Hyperlinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using a font that contains those icons. I don't know which one they are using but here is another example:

http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

```
element:before {
    content: "\f000";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
```

This loads the icon. Now you only have to apply the css selector on a `span` or `i` or  something else.

Answer (score 2):

It is something called an icon and it is basically a font which is why a size can be specified to make it larger or smaller. I suggest looking at [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) to get a better understanding.

Comment: Font-awesome is fonting awesome!